# A homogeneous function of degree $k$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I think I have proved a proposition about the continuity of homogeneous functions of degree $k$ for a Real Analysis course.

> **Proposition**: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a non-zero function. If $f$ is *homogeneous of degree* $k$: 
>   $$\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}\colon~\forall \,\lambda,x\in\mathbb{R}\colon\qquad f(\lambda x) \,=\, \lambda^{k} f(x),$$
>   then $f$ is continuous.

This is before we have got on to differentiation so it should be proved using $\epsilon,\delta$ arguments. Before tackling the proposition though I proved the following lemma:

> **Lemma** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a non-zero homogeneous function of degree $k$. Then
>
> $$ x \,=\, 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad f(x)\,=\,0.$$
>
> *Proof*: Consider both implications separately:
>
> "$\Longrightarrow$": If $x=0$, then $f(x)=f(0)=f(0\cdot 0)=0\cdot f(0)=0$.
>
> "$\Longleftarrow$": We shall prove the contrapositive. Since $f$ is not the zero function, there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)\neq 0$. From the first implication this implies that $a\neq 0$. Now let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq 0$ then
>
> $$f(x) \,=\,  f\left(\frac{x}{a}\cdot a\right) \,=\, \left(\frac{x}{a} \right)^{k} \cdot f(a) \,\neq\, 0$$
>
> since $f(a),x,a\neq 0\quad\blacksquare.$

Now back to proving the main proposition:

> *Proof*: Let $x,a\in\mathbb{R}=\text{dom}(f)$, then
>
> $$\begin{align}
> |f(x)-f(a)| &\,=\, |f(x\cdot 1) - f(a\cdot 1)| \,=\, |x^{k}\cdot f(1) - a^{k}\cdot f(1) | \,=\, |x^{k}-a^{k}|\cdot |f(1)| \\
>    &\,=\, |x-a|\cdot |Q(x)|\cdot |f(1)|.
> \end{align}$$
>
> where $x^{k}-a^{k}=(x-a)Q(x)$ for some polynomial $Q(x)$ by the Polynomial Remainder Theorem. Thus for any $\epsilon>0$:
>
> $$|f(x)-f(a)| \,\leq\, \epsilon \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad |x-a|\cdot |Q(x)|\cdot |f(1)| \,\leq\,\epsilon.$$
>
> We now consider two cases:
>
> 1. $Q(a)=0$: Since $Q$ is a polynomial, it is analytic and hence its zeros are isolated. Choose $\delta_{1}>0$ such that $|x-a|\leq\delta_{1}$ contains only this isolated zero. Then for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x-a|\leq\delta_{1}$:
>      
>      $$|f(x)-f(a)| \,=\, \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
>                            0, & \text{if}\;\; x\,=\, a \\
>                            |x-a|\cdot |Q(x)|\cdot |f(1)| & \text{if}\;\; x\,\neq\, a
>                        \end{array}\right.$$
>      
>      Thus, when $x=a$ we are done as $|x-a|\leq\delta_{1}\;\Longrightarrow\;|f(x)-f(a)|\leq \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. When $x\neq a$ for $|x-a|\leq\delta_{1}$, we have $Q(x)\neq 0$ and hence for any $\epsilon>0$:
>      
>      $$ |f(x)-f(a)|\,\leq\,\epsilon \quad\Longleftrightarrow  |x-a|  \,\leq\,\delta_{2}\,=\,\frac{\epsilon}{|Q(x)|\cdot |f(1)|},$$
>      
>      since $f(1)$ is non-zero by the lemma above. Thus, with $\delta=\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})$, we have shown that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x\in\text{dom}(f)$ and
>      
>      $$|x-a|\,\leq\,\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(a)|\,\leq\,\epsilon|.$$
> 2. $Q(a)\neq 0$: Since $Q$ is continuous, there exists a neighbourhood of $x=a$ for which $Q$ does not vanish; let $\delta_{1}>0$ be such that $|x-a|\leq\delta_{1}$ defines this interval of non-vanishing $Q$, then:
>      
>      $$|f(x)-f(a)| \,\leq\, \epsilon \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad |x-a|  \,\leq\,\delta_{2}\,=\,\frac{\epsilon}{|Q(x)|\cdot |f(1)|},$$
>      
>      since $f(1)\neq 0$ from the lemma above. Therefore, with $\delta=\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})>0$, we have shown that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x\in\text{dom}(f)$ and                 
>      
>      $$|x-a| \,\leq\,\delta \quad\Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|\,\leq\,\epsilon.$$
>
> These two cases imply the result. $\quad\blacksquare$

My main issues were with the very last bit where I wanted to divide by $|Q(x)|$ so wanted to make sure that it didn't vanish, which led me to considering the two cases when $Q(a)=0$ and $Q(a)\neq 0$. I think the proof is okay but I wouldn't be surprised if there is an easier method or way of combining these two cases. Any comments/suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: There is one issue with all formulations and reasonings here: (1) nothing guarantees that $[a,b]$ contains $0$ or $1$; (2) the definition of a homogeneous function is given for a function defined on $\Bbb R$, not on $[a,b]$.

Comment: To illustrate these remarks: consider a function $f:[2,3]\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=1/x$. It is clearly a homogeneous function of degree $k=-1$, yet it is not defined in $x=0$. And without addition hypothesis we can not talk about $f(1)$ either.

Comment: Agreed @TZakrevskiy - I will edit the post to define the function on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Since $f(0)$ is well-defined, we obtain that $k\ge 0$ (note that your reasoning in the first lemma would not work for $k<0$). After that, you get for free that $f(x) = x^kf(1)$; in other words, $f$ is a polynomial, and polynomials are continuous (there is a proof in any book on analysis).

Comment: Neat @TZakrevskiy. I understand your point about $k>0$ - but I am unsure about $k=0$ now: I don't think we can use the argument to show $f(0)=0$ for this case either. Is there any way to extend it to $k<0$?

Comment: There are no non-zero homogeneous functions of a strictly negative degree defined over the whole $\Bbb R$ - the problem arises in $x=0$, you will necessarily have a singularity there. For $k=0$ the only homogeneous function (with respect to your definition) is a constant function, and, indeed, we can very well have $f(0)=1$ in this case; this does not bother us much, since constant functions are continuous=)

Comment: There are approaches when we consider only $\lambda > 0$. In this case, the behaviour of $f$ for $x>0$ is somewhat disjoint from its behaviour for $x<0$; you will lose continuity for $k=0$, but for $k>0$ it still holds.